# Using df.loc to place a value from a different row

Tags: python, pandas

I'm pulling my hair out on this one. Help appreciated.

I have a dataframe I'm munging which partially involves consolidating data that resides on several rows into one. I'm trying to use df.loc to do it:

```
df.loc[df['foo'] == 1, 'Output Column'] = df.loc[df['bar'] == 2, 'Desired Column']
```

So what I want is for any row where 'foo' = 1, go look for where 'bar' = 2 and put the value that resides in the 'Desired Column' into the original row. Essentially this will consolidate the rows to create cleaner output. As a toy example...

(Edited to show where my code is going wrong)
Here's what I want...
Before:

```
idx   foo     bar    Desired Column    Output Column
0     1
1             2      Hi there!
2     1
3     6
```

After:

```
idx   foo     bar    Desired Column    Output Column
0     1                                Hi there!
1             2      Hi there!    
2     1                                Hi there!
3     6
```

However here's what I'm actually getting:
Before:

```
idx   foo     bar    Desired Column    Output Column
0     1
1             2      Hi there!
2     1
3     6
```

After:

```
idx   foo     bar    Desired Column    Output Column
0     1                                
1             2      Hi there!         Hi there!
2     1                                
3     6
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Does mine solve the problem

Comment: You're doing it right. What is the question here?

Comment: @tozCSS Its that if the `foo` columns is 1 assign the column `'Output Column'`  to the row that `'bar'` columns is 2's `'Desired Column'`

Comment: @tozCSS let me clarify... see edits

Comment: @U9-Forward This isn't quite it, let me clarify

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this worked... not sure it is the most pythonic solution ever but here it goes:

```
df.loc[df['foo'] == 1, 'Output Column'] = df.loc[df['bar'] == 2, 'Desired Column']
df['Output Column'] = df.groupby(['foo'])['Output Column'].transform(max)
```

In my toy example, this populated with the single number that corresponded to bar=2

Answer (score 0):

Try using `where`:

```
df['Output Column']=df['Output Column'].where(df['bar']==2,'Hi There!')
print(df)
```

Output:

```
    idx   foo     bar    Desired Column    Output Column
0   0     1       NaN    NaN               Hi there!
1   1     NaN     2      Hi there!         NaN
```

To replace NaN's with `''`, do:

```
df=df.fillna('')
```

after `where`.

Then:

```
print(df)
```

Will be:

```
    idx   foo     bar    Desired Column    Output Column
0   0     1                                Hi there!
1   1             2      Hi there!
```

Or more dis-manually , do:

```
df['Output Column']=df['Output Column'].where(df['bar']==2,df.loc[df['bar']==2,'Desired Column'].tolist())
print(df)
```

Then can do same thing to replace NaN's  with `''`

## Update:

#### First:

```
df['Output Column']=df['Output Column'].where(df['foo']!=1,'Hi There!')
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
  Desired Column Output Column  bar  foo  idx
0            NaN     Hi There!  NaN  1.0    0
1      Hi There!           NaN  2.0  NaN    1
2            NaN     Hi There!  NaN  1.0    2
3            NaN           NaN  NaN  6.0    3
```

#### Second:

```
df['Output Column']=df['Output Column'].where(df['foo'].notnull(),'Hi There!')
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
  Desired Column Output Column  bar  foo  idx
0            NaN           NaN  NaN  1.0    0
1      Hi There!     Hi There!  2.0  NaN    1
2            NaN           NaN  NaN  1.0    2
3            NaN           NaN  NaN  6.0    3
```

**Can do Same Thing to replace NaN's with `''`**

Comment: Tried this. It puts the "Hi there!" in the right place, but it assumes I know what is actually in column 'bar' in the first place. I want it to go find that value. FWIW, I tried changing your code to 'df[bar]' instead of 'Hi there!' and that just took the 'Desired Column' value from the 'foo' = 1 row, not from the 'bar' = 2 row.

Comment: @Tom Let me try